# MARS MIPS CLI does not accept newline character when read char syscall is called and instead returns an error

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I have the following program that reads a character and prints it:

```
.macro print_char
    li $v0, 11
    lbu $a0, ($s0)
    syscall
.end_macro
 
.macro read_char
    li $v0, 12
    syscall
    sb $v0, ($s0)
.end_macro
 
.text
    # Initialize registers.
    li $s0, 0x10010000
    li $t0, 0x0
 
    read_char
    print_char
```

It works in the MARS MIPS IDE, I can press the `Enter` key and the simulator will print a newline. But when I try to do the same thing using the MARS MIPS CLI, it returns an `invalid char input (syscall 12)` error. Why is this?

Comment: What's the MARS MIPS CLI?  Do you have a reference on the web for it?

Comment: @ErikEidt You can run an assembly program directly on the command line with MARS by simply appending the filename to the command line, e.g. `java -jar Mars4_5.jar foo.s`

Comment: @ErikEidt https://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/Help/Help_4_1/MarsHelpCommand.html

Comment: I get that error using the MARS MIPS IDE, when the following of Settings is selected "Popup dialog box for input syscalls (5,6,7,8,12)", but not when this setting is unselected.  (A return appears to be taken as a mouse click on the OK button without having entered any text.) Is is possible to verify or disable this setting with the CLI?

Comment: Are you getting a dialog box with the CLI?

Comment: No, there is no dialog box. I run my command as `java -jar path/to/mars.jar test.asm` in the CLI and I just press `Enter` afterwards. Interestingly, I tried running `java -jar v0 path/to/mars.jar test.asm` which will print the content of register $v0 after the program ends, and it outputs `$v0     0x0000000c` which means the register receives my input. It's weird that it returns an error.

Comment: Yeah, I see that, too in the IDE version.  Note that 0xc is form feed (0xa is line feed, and 0xd is carriage return), though I'm getting it to.  If I turn on an exception handler it does go to run the exception handler.  I suppose you could use an exception handler to change the 0xc into an 0xd and resume the program!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code contains an exception handler, that handles the exception on the bad input for syscall #12, then changes the 0xc to 0xd; advances the exception pc (epc) and resumes the user code:

```
.macro print_char
    li $v0, 11
    lbu $a0, ($s0)
    syscall
.end_macro
 
.macro read_char
    li $v0, 12
    syscall
    sb $v0, ($s0)
.end_macro
 
.text
    # Initialize registers.
    li $s0, 0x10010000
    li $t0, 0x0
 
    read_char
    print_char
    
    li $v0, 10
    syscall             # terminate program
    


.ktext 0x80000180       # install this next code as kernel exception handler
    li $v0, 0xd         # change 0xc in $v0 to 0xd
    mfc0 $k1, $14       # fetch epc (address of the offending syscall)
    addi $k1, $k1, 4    # advance to next instruction
    mtc0 $k1, $14       # update epc
    eret                # resume user code
```

Note that this handler has absolutely no error checking — in particular, it assumes that the only reason it might be invoked is to handle that syscall #12 error.